# This backslash in my FRC vision program is not an escape sequence, but I cannot figure out what it is?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have absolutely no idea what the backslash at the end of the first line does. I have searched high and low.

```
camera = CameraServer.getInstance() \
     .startAutomaticCapture(name=config.name, path=config.path)
```

Comment: It's a line continuation

Comment: It's called "explicit line joining" in the official docs: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#explicit-line-joining